# Inject instance in view Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I need help to inject two instances in view,

```
    public function future($property, EodFuturesDataTable $dataTable1, EodBhavDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        $dataTable->property = $property;
        $dataTable1->property = $property;
        return $dataTable->render('pages/apps.symbol.overview_future', compact('property'));
    }
```

And in view, I can access the table as below, and it working fine for `dataTable`, now I want to print the same for `dataTable1`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    {{ $dataTable->table() }}
</div>
```

I tried to pass it in `compact` as like below, but then it ended with an  error,

```
return $dataTable->render('pages/apps.symbol.overview_future', compact('property', 'dataTablel1'));
```

Here is what it returns if I pass `dataTable1`

```
Call to undefined method App\DataTables\EodFuturesDataTable::table()
```

So how to inject `dataTable1` same as `dataTable` ?

Comment: what does render do? what is a `EodFuturesDataTable`?

Comment: It renders YajraDataTable, https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/quick-starter . Here they rendered only one table, but I want to render two tables on same view.

Comment: why not `return view(...)` and pass both tables there?

Comment: @krisgjika, if i use ```view()``` it does not call ```table()``` method in view to print table, it always says ```Call to undefined method App\DataTables\EodFuturesDataTable::table()``` and even then ```dataTable``` will not print in html, means both table will show errors,

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633297/laravel-datatables-multiple-tables-on-one-view

Comment: @krisgjika, it seems more complex with two tables in YajraTables, so I switched to Powergrid with livewire, seems much easy than that :-)

Answer (score 0):

To inject multiple instances into your view and access them separately, you need to pass both instances to the view using an associative array in the compact function. Here's how you can modify your controller code:

```
 public function future($property, EodFuturesDataTable $dataTable1, 
   EodBhavDataTable $dataTable)
 {
  $dataTable->property = $property;
  $dataTable1->property = $property;

// Pass both instances to the view
   return $dataTable->render('pages/apps.symbol.overview_future', 
   compact('property', 'dataTable', 'dataTable1'));
}
```

Then, in your view, you can access both instances separately. Here's how you can render them:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <!-- Render first instance (dataTable) -->
     {{ $dataTable->table() }}
 </div>

  <div class="table-responsive">
      <!-- Render second instance (dataTable1) -->
      {{ $dataTable1->table() }}
  </div>
```

By passing both instances in the compact function, you can access them separately in your view using the variable names ($dataTable and $dataTable1). Make sure to use the correct variable name when calling the table() method on each instance.

Comment: It will throw same errors ```Call to undefined method App\DataTables\EodFuturesDataTable::table()``` if i pass with compact method, it will print table only if used with render(), as ```$dataTable```